# To read FILE and store data in map<string, vector<string>> c++98

Tags: c++, file, dictionary, vector, c++98

I have file bird.lst, I need to read file contents and store data in map<string, vector>, here the idea is bird name is store in string and those having some attribute values that needs to be stored in vector.  please help

eventually map<string, vector> looks like below,
ex:

```
 parrot.sh   ---->  eat    yes
                    fly    yes
```

file contents below of bird.lst

```
parrot.sh
eat    yes
fly    yes

pigeon.sh
eat    yes
fly    yes

duck.sh
eat   yes
fly   no

flammingo.sh
eat   yes
fly   yes

eagle.sh
eat    yes
flay   yes
```

Comment: You don't actually say what kind of problem you are having getting it to work, so I have made an answer - if it doesn't actually answer your question let me know.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah this solution works perfectly fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested loop.

- The outside one reads the name of the bird (the key of the map)
- The inside one reads the attributes of the bird (the values of the vector)

Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


typedef std::vector<std::string> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string,attribute_vector> bird_map;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("bird.lst");

    bird_map birds;
    std::string key;
    while(std::getline(file,key))
    {
        attribute_vector attributes;
        std::string value;
        while(std::getline(file,value))
        {
            // in case it has windows encoding with end-of-line = \r\n
            if (!value.empty() &&
                value[value.size()-1] == '\r')
            {
                value.erase(value.size() - 1);
            }

            // if we found the empty string
            if(value.empty())
            {
                break;
            }

            // save the value into the vector
            attributes.push_back(value);
        }
        // save the bird into the map
        birds[key] = attributes;
    }

    // now print the data we collected
    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        bird++)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            attribute++)
        {
            std::cout << "    " << *attribute << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/1TBobUxE2  (it says `C++17` as the compiler type but in the config under "Extra Compiler Flags" I am passing `-std=c++98`)

If you want to split the attribute from the yes/no value then:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> attribute_pair;
typedef std::vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string,attribute_vector> bird_map;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("bird.lst");

    bird_map birds;
    std::string key;
    while(std::getline(file,key))
    {
        attribute_vector attributes;
        std::string value;
        while(std::getline(file,value))
        {
            // in case it has windows encoding with end-of-line = \r\n
            if (!value.empty() &&
                value[value.size()-1] == '\r')
            {
                value.erase(value.size() - 1);
            }

            // if we found the empty string
            if(value.empty())
            {
                break;
            }

            // now split the value into an attribute and a flag
            attribute_pair attribute;
            std::istringstream ss(value);
            ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;

            // save the value into the vector
            attributes.push_back(attribute);
        }
        // save the bird into the map
        birds[key] = attributes;
    }

    // now print the data we collected
    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        bird++)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            attribute++)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << attribute->first
                      << " = " << attribute->second
                      << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/Htlh4eHu9  (it says `C++17` as the compiler type but in the config under "Extra Compiler Flags" I am passing `-std=c++98`)

Answer (score 0):

*(Issue)* The problem is not very specific.
So I'll try to make a very general solution.
Define a function:

```
bool is_file(string s) {
   return (s.substr((int)s.size() - 3, 3) == ".sh");
}
```

Telling you if a string is a bird file.

Because of *(Issue)*, I'll asume each attribute of the bird is of the form: (attribute, yes/no), wich we'll transform to (attribute, 1/0).

Now, to read the file, you have several options. I'll name two of them.

1. Pass the file from console, i.e, if you .exe is called birds.exe, just do birds.exe<bird.lst. And just read with std::cin.
2. Use freopen("bird.lst", "r", stdin); and just read with std::cin.

Then, the main function should look like this:

```
int main () {
   freopen("bird.lst", "r", stdin); // if you didnt read from console.
   map<string, vector<pair<string, bool>>> birds;
   string current_bird;
   while (cin >> s) {
       string s;
       cin >> s;
       if (is_file(s)) {
          current_bird = s;
          continue;
       }
       bool verdict;
       cin >> verdict;
       bird[current_bird].push_back(make_pair(s, verdict));
   }
}
```

And to print the data:

```
for (auto it = birds.begin(); it != birds.end(); it++) {
   cout << "Bird File: " << it.first << "\n";
   cout << "Attributes:\n";
   for (auto x : it.second) cout << x.first << " " << (x.second ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: In `is_file` you have a typo where you use `n` instead of `s` and with c++98 you can't have nested templates with `>>>` at the end - you need spaces in between because when c++98 compilers see two `>` in a row thy thing it is a right shift operator.  And in c++98 `auto` doesn't do what expect.

Comment: I see. Well, you know what to do haha. I fixed the typo and added a printing algorithm. I really want the best answer, so I get more benefits haha, I'm new and I have almost none :c

Comment: For the auto issue, replace it with map<string, vector<pair<string, bool>>>::iterator :D

Comment: There are a bunch of other bugs, the worst of which is `cin >> verdict;` to a bool variable when the file contains a string of `yes` or `no`  If you want to use it, here is a version with all those bugs fixed: https://onlinegdb.com/Bk1mGhBNd